# Database Compatibility Level SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

My SQL Server 2008 R2 database compatibility is currently set to 100.

Is it possible to set the compatibility level to a higher value - say 130 to use some new features?

Comment: No you **cannot** - SQL Server 2008 R2 **is** level 100 - you cannot just set the value higher and get new features that way. You need to actually **UPGRADE** your SQL Server engine to get these new features.

Answer (score 1):

No. Each version of SQL Server has a range comparability level it supports, and that range is determined by the version.

Here's the list of supported compatibility levels from [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) Compatibility Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017):

```
Product                             Database Engine Version     Compatibility Level Designation     Supported Compatibility Level Values
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL Server 2019 preview             15                          150                                 150, 140, 130, 120, 110, 100
SQL Server 2017 (14.x)              14                          140                                 140, 130, 120, 110, 100
Azure SQL Database logical server   12                          130                                 150, 140, 130, 120, 110, 100
Azure SQL Database Managed Instance 12                          130                                 150, 140, 130, 120, 110, 100
SQL Server 2016 (13.x)              13                          130                                 130, 120, 110, 100
SQL Server 2014 (12.x)              12                          120                                 120, 110, 100
SQL Server 2012 (11.x)              11                          110                                 110, 100, 90
SQL Server 2008 R2                  10.5                        100                                 100, 90, 80
SQL Server 2008                     10                          100                                 100, 90, 80
SQL Server 2005 (9.x)               9                           90                                  90, 80
SQL Server 2000                     8                           80                                  80
```

As you can see, 2008 R2 supports only 100, 90 and 80 compatibility levels.